# background image affects height of ConstraintLayout and Relativelayout differently

Tags: android, performance, background-image, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

I am converting relativLayout into ConstraintLayout, so the viewGroup (relativelayout)  has a height of wrap_content, relativeLayout is effected by the background while constraintLayout is not.

It will be clear with the screenshot included.

ConstraintLayout :
[image: ConstraintLayout's height only depends on android:height attribute value]

RelativeLayout :
[image: Relative layout took more space in. height if background image needed more space]

So I want to make my contraintLayout look the same as in relativelayout.
One way is to give verticle margin.
Would like to know why these layout behave differently and what is the better way to achieve this.

Comment: Could you post the rest of the layout file? I wonder if that textview in the middle there needs constraints that you aren't expecting.

Comment: A view's background expands to fill its view and not the other way around which would indicate that the views has a different size without the background. What is the nature of the background drawable?